# Как добавить скрипт с другого сайта во Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, статистика

Вот например на сайте яндекса есть такое. Npm пакета я не нашел, и где скачать нормальные форматированые.js файлы я тоже не нашел. Как в итоге подключить это во Vue?

Подключите скрипт блока:

```
<script src="https://yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://yastatic.net/share2/share.js" async="async"></script>
```

А как это подключить во Vue?

Comment: Вставить код выше в head файла html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы не хотите, вставлять данные скрипты в index.html и вам, допустим, надо чтобы эти скрипты подключались при загрузке конкретного компонента, в хуке жизненного цикла mounted() этого компонента вы можете их вставить, таким образом:

```
    const insertScript = document.createElement('script')
    insertScript.setAttribute('src', 'url_of_your_script')
    document.body.appendChild(insertScript)
```